# Gitlab CI/CD runner and docker connection configuration

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to configure gitlab CI/CD runner. On the runner, I have deployed maven and java that builds my project and executes the test. So far so good, but the final step which it should pakage the code as a docker image and deploy fails. Here is the script which runs fine in cloud.But it says docker command not found in local, and I did not understand the workflow. Now for that to run, am I supposed to install docker on to my runner ? As the runner itself is a container inside docker. I could not figure out what should I do for this step to run. Please help.

```
docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/imran_yusubov/gs-spring-boot-docker .
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - docker push registry.gitlab.com/imran_yusubov/gs-spring-boot-docker
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you starting the runner?

The proper way to start the runner would be:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

Where you pass your docker socket and then in your pipeline you would have to call the docker:dind service in order to be able to run Docker in Docker which will allow you to build Docker images and run containers

You could find more info in this [tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. and the excellent guide. Despite searching for it couple of days, I could not find it. Probably, this is the missing part, I will test it asap and update the thread.

Comment: Started it in this way but still it says docker command not found. This is the part,  failing                                                                                   docker-build: